# getting ReadOnlyObjectWrapper value to a label

Tags: java, javafx

I have been think for somedays how to fix this but i need someone’s help.
I have a 2 tableviews and one is fill up with data. and if customer clicked on a row it gets it to other tableview. but the problem is with total price which supposed to dynamical add any item pick by a user.
I got this code and is perfect but I can’t seem to get the total to label and not in a row.

**model**

```
 private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Double> total = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>();

        public LineItemProperty(String name, Integer quantity, Double unitPrice) {
            setName(name);
            setQuantity(quantity);
            setUnitPrice(unitPrice);

            // Obvious binding for the total of this line item: 
            // total = quantity * unit price
            total.bind(Bindings.createObjectBinding(new Callable<Double>() {
                @Override
                public Double call() throws Exception {
                    if (quantityProperty().get() == null || unitPriceProperty().get() == null) {
                        return 0.0;
                    }else{
                    return quantityProperty().get() * unitPriceProperty().get();
                    }
                }
            }, quantityProperty(), unitPriceProperty()));
        }
```

**in view**

```
   table.getColumns().add(column("Total Price", LineItemProperty::totalProperty, false, null));

    final Label selected = new Label("Total");
```

**another class for total**

```
public class LineItemListWithTotal extends TransformationList<LineItemProperty, LineItemProperty>{

        private final TotalLine totalLine;

        public LineItemListWithTotal(
                ObservableList<? extends LineItemProperty> source) {
            super(source);
            totalLine = new TotalLine(source);
        }

        @Override
        protected void sourceChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends LineItemProperty> c) {

            // no need to modify change:
            // indexes generated by the source list will match indexes in this
            // list

            fireChange(c);
        }
```

Thanx a lot. any idea will help and appreciated

Comment: `I can’t seem to get the total to label and not in a row` Not sure exactly what you mean, do you have a JavaFX `Label` that you want the value displayed on? Does your "total price" work?

Comment: Why do you add this property to the `LineItemProperty` class, which seems to be a class containing data about a single "item pick", if the data you're trying to collect obvously depends on multiple items? What are you trying to accomplish with a `TransformationList`? You're not trying to do anything similar to a `FilteredList` or a `SortedList`...

Comment: Thanx Guys for you participation. MikaeIF i have as you said Javafx Label and watn to display the total values each time an item is added. and yes am getting the total but only if i init it with tablecolumn. which i want to avoid.

Comment: Fabian yes LineItemProperties are just object properties which just etc.